# My endlessly spawning terrain sometimes spawns once and sometimes spawns twice. Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am using Unity 3D engine to make a 2D game. I want to create endlessly repeating terrain. I got it to repeat seamlessly, except for the fact that sometimes two terrains will spawn at once. It happens randomly and without any good reason. Any help?

This is my terrain respawn code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using PlayerPrefs = GamePlayerPrefs;
public class SelfTerrainSpawn : MonoBehaviour {
    // terrain references
    public GameObject first;
    public GameObject second;
    public GameObject third;
    public GameObject fourth;
    public GameObject fifth;
    public GameObject sixth;
    public GameObject seventh;
    public float spawnXPos = 0.0f;
    public float respawnCoordinate = 30.4f;
    public float respawnTriggerCoordinate = -21.7f;
    public bool canSpawn = true;
    public bool starting = true;
    public float random;

    void Start() {
        this.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector2 (0.0f, 31.4f);
        this.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, 90.0f);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        // if the camera is farther than the number last position minus 16 terrain is spawned
        // a lesser number may make the terrain 'pop' into the scene too early
        // showing the player the terrain spawning which would be unwanted
        if (this.gameObject.transform.position.y <= respawnTriggerCoordinate && canSpawn)
        {
            // turn off spawning until ready to spawn again
            random = Random.Range(0,18);
            SpawnTerrain (random);
            canSpawn = false;
        }
        if (this.gameObject.transform.position.y <= respawnTriggerCoordinate - 10) {
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
    }
    void SpawnTerrain(float rand) {
        if ((rand == 0)) {
            Instantiate (first, new Vector3 (respawnCoordinate, spawnXPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
        }
        if ((rand >= 1) && (rand <= 4)) {
            Instantiate (second, new Vector3 (respawnCoordinate, spawnXPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
        }
        if ((rand >= 5) && (rand <= 8)) {
            Instantiate (third, new Vector3 (respawnCoordinate, spawnXPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
        }
        if ((rand >= 9) && (rand <= 10)) {
            Instantiate (fourth, new Vector3 (respawnCoordinate, spawnXPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
        }
        if ((rand >= 10) && (rand <= 13)) {
            Instantiate (fifth, new Vector3 (respawnCoordinate, spawnXPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
        }
        if ((rand >= 13) && (rand <= 15)) {
            Instantiate (sixth, new Vector3 (respawnCoordinate, spawnXPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
        }
        if ((rand >= 15) && (rand <= 18)) {
            Instantiate (seventh, new Vector3 (respawnCoordinate, spawnXPos, 0), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

This script is attached to the first terrain piece, inside of the game:

[Click here to see an image of the game screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyeBd.png)

It is also attached to the other two prefabs. Each of these prefabs also have a script that moves them down the screen slowly. Basically, when one's top reaches the top of the camera, another is supposed to spawn above the camera. Then it moves down and repeats. See that I used the canSpawn variable to make sure that it only spawns once. However, at random, two terrains will spawn on top of each other. Can anybody give me a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `rand` is 10, 13, or 15, you'll generate two terrains because your range checks overlap for those values.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thats not the only problem solved, you MUST use `IF ELSEIF` not only `IF IF IF IF IF`...

Comment: hi @MilesKim are you there?  As a new user it's important you TICK an answer.  it's the green "TICK" symbol to your left.

Comment: Sorry, It told me I had to wait 2 minutes, and then I got sidetracked